# SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure

Tags: linux, postfix-mta, sasl

LAMP using postfix/dovecot

Getting a ton of these in mail.warn and fail2ban is blocking IP's left and right:
postfix/smtpd[10117]: warning: [domain name here]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure

I'm a little nervous that these might be legitimate connection attempts in postfix/smtpd.

If I'm getting an authentication failure is it safe to assume that it's a break-in attempt or could it be a mis-configuration?  Legitimate email is being delivered correctly.  Can't tell anything useful from mail.log, is there anywhere else I should look to see if it's malicious?

Comment: This is more of a system administration than a programming question so it’s off-topic for StackOverflow.

You’d have a much better chance of getting useful answers at [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

In this case, I’d choose Server Fault as there are over [3,000 questions with the Postfix tag](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/postfix?sort=newest) (with close to 400 followers).